# Issue with android appcpmpat_v7 libraries , please go through the whole content

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey Guys I need Some help here  , I was testing and creating Apps with android 4.4 W and 2.2 froyo and recently I chose to install the Other android sdks such as 4.4.2 , 4.2.2 respectively and from there after I am getting the Above Error mentioned , I tried adding support libraries for the project and tried a couple of things mentioned on stackoverflow .

the errors when we first build the project are :

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\android-workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
C:\Userprofile\Documents\android-workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
C:\Userprofile\Documents\android-workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
```

the following are the errors : and not able to resolve android R Issue when i create a new project and working on it

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 75 Android AAPT Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\user\Documents\android-workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

> Right Click on the project
>
> Go to properties.
>
> Click Android from left.
>
> In right you will see a list of android versions. Check the one with api level more than 18.
>
> Click Ok, Now clean your project and rebuilt it again.

Hop it will remove your error.

Comment: my preferences are set to APi level 19.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the **`<style>`** tag in the themes.xml file from the values-v21 folder and values-v14, values-v11 cleared this issue for me...